# ElasticSearch sort buckets based on a list

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, bucket

In a `terms` aggregation query, I want to order the buckets based on

1. an external sorted list - If the item exists in this external sorted list, it should use this
2. bucket internal aggregations like sum - When it does not exist in the external sorted list, use these aggregations

Example: Let's say in ES we get the buckets for `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`. The external sorted list has `[A3, A1]`. And against each buckets we have a sum aggregation as follows:

```
A1: 20
A2: 30
A3: 10
A4: 60
```

I want the final order as `[A3, A1, A4, A2]`.

How do I write this query? I have seen this use case at document level which people have done using script query. But for sorting buckets, I am unable to see.

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to use a [`bucket_sort` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) with [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting).

However, this is not yet supported but there's an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26570#issuecomment-410068999) which aims at tackling this.

Comment: I could expose a scripted metric aggregation using ids indexOf method. But could not use that in ordering. Thank you for the update link